# AWS ECS Service Definition: Role property

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, elastic-load-balancer, aws-alb

I am setting up an AWS ECS Service using cloudformation and yaml syntax.

At some point, in the relevant [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html) there is a property called `Role` whose definitions is the following:

> **Role**
>
> The name or ARN of an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that allows your Amazon ECS container agent to make calls to your
>   load balancer.
>
> **Note** In some cases, you might need to add a dependency on the service role's policy. For more information, see IAM role policy in
>   DependsOn Attribute.
>       Required: No
>       Type: String
>       Update requires: Replacement

Since I intend to place the specific service behind an **Application Load Balancer**, is this property needed?

If so, do I need to create a new policy or are there any pre-defined policies that can serve this purpose?

Would it be enough if I just added the role/policy on the EC2 container instance level (e.g. append it in the [relevant template](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation/blob/master/infrastructure/ecs-cluster.yaml#L242) that creates the ECS cluster offered by amazon?)

I would really appreciate any examples or use cases if any because the documentation is vague and incomplete on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Role attribute if you want to use the `Application Load balancer` with your `ECS service`. As per the description the role allows your `ECS` service agent to connect to load balancer. If you are not using load balancer then, the field is optional.

Also setting the role on `EC2` instance level is not needed. Since there are some policies which are related to ECS services, adding it at instance level role is not valid.

Please find below **AWS managed polices** to create the role:

```
{
"AttachedPolicies": [
    {
        "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole",
        "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole"
    },
    {
        "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role",
        "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
    },
    {
        "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole",
        "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole"
    }
 ]
}
```

**Trust relationship**:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If not assign role to instance it will get register with ECS cluster. Instance level role is imported while service can be linked with load balancer if you checked update view of AWS they not ask for service role as there is task definition role

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/07/amazon-ec2-container-service-now-supports-iam-roles-for-tasks/

Comment: @Adiii instance level role are different than the service level role. Task defination role and service role are different. task defination role are specific to your task. it has nothing to do with load balancer

Answer (score 0):

To register your service with application load balancer you need the role for the service itself, but some permission needs for ECS container to register with cluster.

> Amazon Elastic Container Service uses AWS Identity and Access
>   Management (IAM) service-linked roles. A service-linked role is a
>   unique type of IAM role that is linked directly to Amazon ECS.
>   Service-linked roles are predefined by Amazon ECS and include all the
>   permissions that the service requires to call other AWS services on
>   your behalf.
>
> A service-linked role makes setting up Amazon ECS easier because you
>   don’t have to manually add the necessary permissions. Amazon ECS
>   defines the permissions of its service-linked roles, and unless
>   defined otherwise, only Amazon ECS can assume its roles. The defined
>   permissions include the trust policy and the permissions policy, and
>   that permissions policy cannot be attached to any other IAM entity.

So if you check this role this contain property

```
"elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
```

To **Debug** remove the role to service , it will not register.

If you create service using console by default it attach the role.

> Amazon ECS needs permissions to register and deregister container
>   instances with your load balancer when tasks are created and stopped.
>
> In most cases, the Amazon ECS service role is automatically created
>   for you in the Amazon ECS console first run experience. You can use
>   the following procedure to check and see if your account already has
>   an Amazon ECS service role.

This managed polici by AWS having ARN

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole
Policy ARN
```

> arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole 
>   Description Default policy for Amazon ECS service role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/check-service-role.html

this is how its look like

[image]

If you do not assign a role to ECS container instance it will never show in you ECS cluster and it will throw an error

```
2018-09-06T15:26:22Z [ERROR] Could not register: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

under `/var/logs/ecs`

```
tail -f ecs-agent.log.2018-09-06
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html

Comment: Your highlighted statement and your code are making contradictory statement. In text you are asking to use service linked role but in code you are trying to suggest role at instance level