# AWS ECS: IAM related error when creating ECS service via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create an ECS service via the following manifest:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: 'CloudFormation template for ui service definition'
Resources:

  UIService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !ImportValue MyCSClusterName
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: EC2
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !ImportValue UIContainerName
          ContainerPort: '80'
          TargetGroupArn: !ImportValue UITGArn
      Role: !Ref UIServiceRole
      ServiceName: ui-service
      ServiceRegistries:
       - RegistryArn: arn:aws:servicediscovery:eu-west-1:4309430903:service/srv-oh45959hj55yesez7
      TaskDefinition: !ImportValue UITaskArn


  UIServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer', 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets',
              'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*', 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer',
              'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets', 'ec2:Describe*', 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress']
            Resource: '*'
```

The creation via amazon console fails with the following error which I have no idea what is about.

> You cannot specify an IAM role for services that require a service linked role.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this terraform github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4657), some people resolved this error by removing the IAM role from the manifest (`Role: !Ref UIServiceRole`). Maybe worth a shot?

Comment: Yes but according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198433/aws-ecs-service-definition-role-property discussion, a role is necessary if my service needs to access  (be accessed by) an ALB

Answer (score 0):

The ECS service will in most cases make the IAM role AWSServiceRoleForECS when you create a cluster or role needing to do some ECS activities.  Cloudformation can sometimes have problems with timing for this;  2 ways around this

(1) in you cloudformation ensure the ECSCluster has a depends on for an IAM role that has access to ecs services; in your example `DependsOn: UIServiceRole`

another seeming more 'proper' approach
(2) in your cloudformation add a new resource [IAM Service Linked Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-servicelinkedrole.html) as

```
  ECSServiceLinkedRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ServiceLinkedRole'
    Properties:
      AWSServiceName: ecs.amazonaws.com
      Description: ECS Service Linked Role
```

Note: is the Service Linked Role exists in an account already and you define the struct you must ensure the Description matches (Cloudformation will not support changing the description)

related to [Unable to assume service linked role when using ecs-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877475/unable-to-assume-service-linked-role-when-using-ecs-cli)