# Unable to assume service linked role when using ecs-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm attempting to follow the [ecs-cli Fargate deployment tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html) and have hit a problem attempting to deploy my service.

I am attempting to deploy my test container using `ecs-cli compose --project-name tutorial-maltz service up` but I am getting an error which says `"InvalidParameterException: Unable to assume the service linked role. Please verify that the ECS service linked role exists.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id`

So far I have created my IAM permission using the steps provided, and have verified that I have an IAM role `ecsTaskExecutionRole` which contains an `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`.  This policy also has a trust relationship which looks like the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

All of this is being deployed off of a `ecs-params.yml` file which looks like the following:

```
version: 1
task_definition:
    task_execution_role: ecsTaskExecutionRole
    ecs_network_mode: awsvpc
    task_size:
        mem_limit: 0.5GB
        cpu_limit: 256
run_params:
    network_configuration:
        awsvpc_configuration:
            subnets:
                - "subnet-from-ecs-cli-up"
            security_groups:
                - "subnet-created-by-ecs-cli-up"
        assign_public_ip: ENABLED
```

I'm not really sure where to look next.  Am I missing an IAM role? Do I need to add some additional parameters to my existing IAM roles?

Answer (score 21):

For future people running into this issue, the solution was to create a [service linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html#create-service-linked-role) for ECS as a whole.  This had to be done by an admin on the AWS account.

Note that this is *different* than the `TaskExecutionRole` which you create earlier in the tutorial.  The service linked role allows ECS to do things like spin up new EC2 instances and create ELB stacks. TaskExecutionRole is *only* for the thing that launches the tasks.

Answer (score 8):

Using my Administrator role, when creating an ECS Cluster, I too was blocked by... "ECS Cluster Unable to assume the service linked role. Please verify that the ECS service linked role exists."
And I verified that indeed the role, *AWSServiceRoleForECS*, existed.

The Fix?  By exercising the "Get Started" wizard, it (re)configured something under the covers and now my Administrator roles is allowed to assume *AWSServiceRoleForECS* and **SUCCESS**fully creates cluster.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me, as the first time I accessed ECS I skipped clicking "Get started"

Comment: From the documentation:
`Under most circumstances, you don't need to manually create the service-linked role. For example, when you create a new cluster (for example, with the Amazon ECS first-run experience, the cluster creation wizard, or the AWS CLI or SDKs), or create or update a service in the AWS Management Console, Amazon ECS creates the service-linked role for you, if it does not already exist.`

Comment: As for late 2022, this is still the only fix for this. I needed to deploy some ECS stuff, via Cloudformation, in a new AWS account and I had to perform your solution to fix the deployment errors.

Answer (score 3):

if anyone is having trouble creating the service linked role for ECS (Role: AWSServiceRoleForECS) open cloudshell (as an admin user) and paste this command in:

```
aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name ecs.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: when i try this command i get "Service role name AWSServiceRoleForECS has been taken in this account, please try a different suffix" any idea of what could be the issue?

Comment: @Sombrinks the role was already created (by you / AWS) due to an action performed on this account either via the CLI or CDK. You can verify in iam. No need to recreate it since it is AWS-managed.